# ToString method and return static string

Tags: c#, string, tostring

Class example:

```
public class SomeType
{
    private int type;

    // some code...

    public override string ToString ()
    {
       if (type == 1) return "One";
       if (type == 2) return "Two";
    }
}
```

Now imagine application calls thousand times `ToString()` method in a second.

My question is: when I use inline created string in code like `something = myClass.ToString()` is in every call created a new string or compiler optimize it somehow? (because strings are immutable it could be returned only referense to a static string).

And if not, should I make static private string fields and return them in `ToString` method for performance reasons?

Ofcourse I will test it using Stopwatch, but I need an expert answer anyway.

Comment: [C# String Theory—String intern pool](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_String_Theory%E2%80%94String_intern_pool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using string literals - which means you're returning a reference to the same string each time. This is *guaranteed* by the language specification. From section 2.4.4.5 of the C# 5 specification:

> When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator (§7.10.7) appear in the same program, these string literals refer to the same string instance.

So as a simpler example:

```
string x = "One";
string y = "One";
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)); // Prints True
```

In your code, the `ToString()` method will still be called - but it won't create a new string object each time. You might consider using a `switch` statement instead of all those `if` statements, by the way.

Note that even if it *did* create a new string each time, creating *thousands* of strings per second won't make a modern CPU break into a sweat. Both the allocator and garbage collector are pretty efficient, and modern computers can do an awful lot of work in a second.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JABFreeware: I've added a bit more detail. If it's still unclear to you, please explain exactly what's unclear.

Comment: So it is like I thought. Thanks for quick answer Sir Skeet.